# Walking through files in directory randomly

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, directory, for

How to change `for track in *.mp3; do` so that all `.mp3` files in the current directory are walked through but in a random way?

Comment: `sort -R` might do what you want

Comment: `mpg123` has `-Z` aka `--random` ;-)

Answer (score 8):

For reference, in `zsh`, you can affect the order globs are expanded with the `o` globbing qualifier. For instance `*.mp3(om)` sorts by modification time. You can define your own sorting order with functions.

With `*.mp3(o+foo)`, the files are sorted, not based on their name but on the value that the `foo` function returns in the `$REPLY` variable for a given filename (and `foo` receives the filename in `$REPLY` as well). So for instance with:

```
rand() REPLY=$RANDOM

for i in *.mp3(o+rand); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

You get a random order.

POSIXly, and if you don't want to make any assumption on what filenames may contain, you could do something like:

```
shuffle() {
  awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN {
    printf "set --"
    for (i=1; i < ARGC; i++) {
      r=int(rand()*(ARGC-1)+1);x=ARGV[i];ARGV[i]=ARGV[r];ARGV[r]=x
    }
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {
      a=ARGV[i];gsub(q, q "\\" q q, a);printf " %s", q a q
    }
    print "";exit}' "$@"
}
eval "$(shuffle *.mp3)"
for i do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `shuf` command to shuffle lines for you. Just backtick a list command where you have *.mp3 and pipe it to `shuf`, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash -
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'; set -f
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp3' -type f | shuf`
do
    echo "$i"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS; set +f
```

The above assumes GNU `find` and that file names don't contain newline characters.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't handle space in filenames correctly this way.

Comment: Issue is just that the OP is using the `for` loop to illustrate their answer, which keys off any whitespace. If you use `find` it works as advertised. [Example](http://dpaste.org/ngKu5/) dougBTV should probably update to something else for clarity, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavis and here's an update that handles the spaces in files. Using the IFS, internal field separator.

Comment: Hm. Find doesn't do the job for me..

Comment: How's that? What exactly are you wanting it to do?

Comment: Any luck with the updated code with the IFS @runbehind ?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas -- good call. Updated with an edit. That's where `find` seems to help. This solution is predicated with newline being the delimiter, so I tested it against everything but files containing backspace and those containing newline.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -name \*.mp3 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | shuf -z | while IFS= read -d '' -r l; do printf %s\\n "$l"; done`

- -maxdepth, -print0, shuf, and read -d are not defined by POSIX. shuf is part of coreutils.
- read strips characters in IFS from the start and end of lines. -r disables interpreting backslashes. `-d ''` is the same as `-d $'\0'`.

Or if the paths don't contains linefeeds or backslashes and they don't start or end with characters in IFS:

`printf %s\\n *.mp3 | shuf | while read l; do printf %s\\n "$l"; done`